# Registering as a new user not getting verification email in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using "RealHomes Theme" for  my project but the problem is while registering as a new user it is successfully adding but unable to get an email verification for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling all of your plugins and using the default theme.

If you're able to register and get the email, turn on all plugins and try again.

- If you still get it, it's an issue with the theme and you should take it up with the developer.
- If not, disable all plugins and change back to your RealHomes theme.

If you get it from there, it's a plugin conflict and you'll have to diagnose that and remove/fix the plugin causing the issue.

However, if you can't get it at all, even with the theme/plugins disabled; it's probably because all-to-often WordPress emails get sent into spam or the void, and it's then an email issue which is harder to diagnose (is it your server, potential blacklisting [use MXToolbox to confirm], email provider issue?).

We had this issue a lot, and to mitigate we started to use wpMandrill and enabled DKIM and SPF on all domains we send from which increased out WP email delivery rate to almost 100%.

Make sure you have DKIM and SPF records for your domain, and are sending from an account that exists on the same domain such as:

`https://example.com/` should be sending emails from something like `WordPress@example.com`